# When must FAA reply to my letter?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

I have sent letters requesting action and/or clarifications to the FAA medical certifications branch.  How long can FAA legally delay before they are required to answer my questions in writing?

Comment: Are you a member of the AOPA? Are you doing this in response to a medical disqualification by your AME? What class medical is this for?

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think any of that is relevant to the question. Is a government agency legally obliged to respond to a letter? I doubt it, though the FAA Administrator might not like hearing that his staff are ignoring people.

Comment: I don't know what you're concern is about, but they are in the middle of a big rule change on 3rd class medical certifications. As far as I've heard they haven't finalized the rules yet. They were given 1 year from July 15th, 2016 to flesh out all the details

Comment: @Ben The AOPA has resources to help for members in this situation. If it is in response to a disqualification by an AME, he would have a reference number and a case file started, if he is just sending letters without a reference number, they will probably not respond. If this is for a first class medical for an airline, the airline may have resources to help. So yes, I believe the questions I asked are relevant. The FAA gets 1800+ medical inquiries per day, so unless he has some case file, he may be ignored just based on volume and cases that have references.

Answer (score 2):

The FAA publication "MEDICAL FACTS FOR PILOTS" Publication #OK-06-002 states the time periods shown below. I don't know of any rule that mandates a response in any specific time period.

*We will respond to your request for duplicate medical certificates within 3 working days of receipt.*

*We will respond to your request for full review of medical records within 30 working days of receipt of all the necessary records and testing.*